# What causes this weird sitar-like sound?

Tags: electric-guitar, sitar

For a few weeks now I've been noticing  that when I play the 7th fret  on the 6th string a get a weird squeak mixing into the sound. Here is audio of me playing the 6th string up to the 7th fret and then some frets around it:

I haven't noticed anything l that on other frets and strings an upon visual inspection  neither the string nor fretboard appear in anyway different on that fret. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 5):

Fret buzz - the next fret up is high & the string is hitting it as you play. You could test with a hard steel rule to see if it rocks when placed edge-on to the fret-board.

A luthier could fix it...
...or if you're a) daring b) skilled or c) poor, you could try tapping it down with a small hammer & a piece of wood placed over the frets so as not to dent them, or d) adventurous, a file. [caveat emptor in all the above]

or you could lift the action, overall or just on that string, depending on your guitar bridge/saddle setup, but that would change how the guitar feels.

Comment: This seems the most likely explanation.  I'm not familiar with the "hard steel rule(r)" test.  Would this be done at each fret?  Presumably one would need to remove all strings before performing the test.

Comment: There's a very detailed guide here - http://www.fernandezmusic.com/ClassicalGuitarSet-up.html Pretty much the same applies to an electric, varnished neck or not.